# Cloning a generic ConfigurationSection without a custom class

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configurationmanager

I'm trying to make a copy of a `ConfigurationSection` from an external app.config file's configuration with the end-goal of merging it into the executing application's currently-loaded configuration.

The purpose is to allow numerous libraries, loaded into individual AppDomains, to receive the configuration from the executing application *and* have their own app.config settings merged so that reading any setting is a simple call to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` or `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()`.

The issue I'm running into is making a clone of a `ConfigurationSection`.

What I've tried:

1. [`ConfigurationSectionCloner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.common.configuration.configurationsectioncloner%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) in the Enterprise Library.

   ```
   Configuration externalConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(externalLibPath);
   var section = externalConfig.GetSection("some.section");
   ConfigurationSectionCloner sectionCloner = new ConfigurationSectionCloner();
   section = sectionCloner.Clone(section);

   Configuration localConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExecConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
   localConfig.Sections.Add("some.section", section);
   ```

   - This runs fine, however, both `localConfig.GetSection("some.section")` and `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("some.section")` are empty.
   - Even calling `localConfig.Save()` (with any combination of parameters) doesn't populate the section.
2. [`CompositeConfigurationSourceHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.common.configuration.compositeconfigurationsourcehandler%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) in the Enterprise Library

   ```
   SystemConfigurationSource localConfig = new SystemConfigurationSource();
   FileConfigurationSource externalConfig = new FileConfigurationSource(externalLibPath + ".config");
   CompositeConfigurationSourceHandler ccsh = new CompositeConfigurationSourceHandler(externalConfig);
   ConfigurationSection section = externalConfig.GetSection("some.section");
   if (!ccsh.CheckAddSection("some.section", section)) {
       try {
           localConfig.Add("some.section", section);
       } catch (Exception) { }
   }
   ```

   - This throws an exception on the `localConfig.add()` line stating `Cannot add a ConfigurationSection that already belongs to the Configuration.`. The problem is that `localConfig` *does not* have that section. Even adding `localConfig.Remove("some.section");` doesn't resolve.
   - I've also tried a number of combinations of `*ConfigurationSource` objects to see if they make a difference but none have.

Copying actual ApplicationSettings from the `appSettings` block, or even ConnectionStrings from the `connectionStrings` block is super-simple with a call such as `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("some key", "some value");` but it doesn't seem as easy with ConfigurationSections.

Is there a way to copy, clone and/or just plain merge a `ConfigurationSection` from one configuration into another?

Notes:

1. I don't want to merge physical files. Everything should happen during runtime and remain in-memory only.
2. I don't want to write a custom class to represent each ConfigurationSection. The sections will be generic and unknown to the executing application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out a method to merge a [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0kca287.aspx) that has been read from any app.config file with the main executing application's loaded config!

The method extends my code for #1 using the [`ConfigurationSectionCloner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.common.configuration.configurationsectioncloner%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) from the [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff672062%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx):

```
// open the external configuration
Configuration externalConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(externalLibPath);

// get the section we're looking to clone & merge
var sectionToClone = externalConfig.GetSection(sectionName);

// "clone" the section; this will create a `DefaultSection` object - not a "pure clone" =[
ConfigurationSectionCloner sectionCloner = new ConfigurationSectionCloner();
var clonedSection = sectionCloner.Clone(sectionToClone);

// set the `Type` of the new section to the one we're cloning (most likely a NameValueCollection)
clonedSection.SectionInformation.Type = sectionToClone.SectionInformation.Type;

// set the new section's XML to match the original one (really? the cloner doesn't do this?!)
clonedSection.SectionInformation.SetRawXml(sectionToClone.SectionInformation.GetRawXml());

// open our local configuration (the "executing application's config)
Configuration localConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExecConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// add the cloned section to it
localConfig.Sections.Add(sectionName, clonedSection);

// save the section (this can be any variation-of-parameters for `.Save()`)
localConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);

// force ConfigurationManager to refresh the new section
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);
```

Oddly, in all of my tests, the above steps are **all** required. The primary ones needed, per-section, are to set the new section's [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.type.aspx), to call [`SetRawXml()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.setrawxml.aspx), and to refresh the section.

The downside to this approach, against what my original desires were, is that the call to `localConfig.Save()` saves it to disk overwriting the original app.config file. Doing this asynchronously in multiple AppDomains causes contention-issues, but that's a different topic!

Comment: After revisiting this, all of the above (the EnterpriseLibrary that is) is fairly over-bloated and could be done with simple XML merging tools (and then using the `SetRawXml()` method)

Comment: I use Entlib 6 and there is no need for retrieving and setting the sectionInformation explicitly, just calling Clone().